# DHARMa problems: Poisson or Zero-inflated negative binomial model?

Tags: residuals, glmm, zero-inflation, diagnostic, glmmtmb

I have a dataset of abundance of of rodent (`AA`) in 63 sites, which located in two main area (northern and southern part, `NS`). AA only appeared in 15 sites, so there are 48 sites have 0 value(mean = 1.349; variance = 11.17). I want to know which environmental factors could explain the abundance of AA, and since there are lots of 0 in my data, so I conducted glmmTMB function to build a `negative-binomial mixed model`(familiy: nbinom2) with `NS` as the random effect.

Model averaging was used to build the model (package`MuMIn`), but the error kept showing up when generating all subsets using `dredge`, and model averaging did not work (Same results when I used nbinom1 family).

> Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See
> vignette('troubleshooting') In fitTMB(TMBStruc)

So I changed the family option to `poisson` and ran the model averaging again, this time the results came out, but I'm not sure if `poisson` distribution fit my data, then I used `DHARMa` to check if there is an overdispersion problem:

```r
test <- glmmTMB(AA ~ PC2 + build + field + shrub + (1|NS/sites) ,  
                family="poisson"(link = "log"), na.action = "na.fail",
                data=Rglmm2) 
res <- simulateResiduals(test)
```

here is the results:

[image]

**Questions:**

Does the results mean the model is fine with poisson distribution? Even there are many 0 value in my data.

I've checked the Owl example (count data) in the [manuscript](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html), but I still not sure if I could chose the poisson distribution for my model based on the diagnostic test results of `DHARMa`.

Comment: The p-value of the dispersion test is 0.832 is indicative of little to no evidence against the hypothesis that there is no overdispersion.   The KS test p-value of 0.178 also indicates little evidence against the hypothesis of (conditionally) Poisson-distributed responses...  Given these two p-values, I'm not sure what the source of your concern is.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks for your reply! I was concerning the distribution of my raw data, which is more like negative binomial rather than poisson, even though the tests of DHARMa seems fine. And I'm also wondering if I could run diagnostic procedure on the model derived from the results of model average.

Comment: Your new data will, just plotted by itself, look more spread out than a Poisson because of the effects of those independent variables changing the mean of the Poisson from one observation to the next...  have you taken that into account?

Comment: I agree with jbowman! Whether it makes sense to fit a mixed model with 4 predictors and a nested RE if you have only 15 non-zero observations is another question!